# Create a geography/geometry column from x and y fields - SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, geometry, sql-server-spatial

I'm new in SQL Server 2008 and I hope you will understand my question/need.

Thus, I have a table which contains 3 fields (Name, Lat and Long) in my data base (spatial). I want to create a geometry/geography column based on those fields (Lat and Long) but unfortunately without any success.

My question is: How can I manage to do that?

Comment: http://www.sql-server-helper.com/sql-server-2008/convert-latitude-longitude-to-geography-point.aspx

Answer (score 40):

You can add a computed column like this

```
alter table yourTable add geographyColumn as geography::STGeomFromText('POINT('+convert(varchar(20),Long)+' '+convert(varchar(20),Lat)+')',4326)
```

I have add the conversion from lng or lat because I store the Long and Lats as numbers.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, I managed to solve my problem using this line: UPDATE yourdatabase SET geometry_column=geometry::Point([ColX], [ColY], SRID)

Comment: It is possible to create a trigger for this? Like when you populate your fields (columns X and Y) with information the script mentioned above will run.

Answer (score 11):

Looks like you want the [`STGeomFromText()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933823.aspx) or [`STPointFromText()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933979.aspx) SQL method:

```
DECLARE @g geography;
SET @g = geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(-122.34900 47.65100)', 4326);
SELECT @g.ToString();
```

or

```
DECLARE @g geography;
SET @g = geography::STPointFromText('POINT(-122.34900 47.65100)', 4326);
SELECT @g.ToString();
```

Create your `Geometry` or `Geography` field, then use SQL to populate that field using your lat/lon values.

Comment: What would be the difference in using the following method instead... `DECLARE @g geometry;
SET @g = geometry::STPointFromText('POINT (100 100)', 0);`

Comment: @awesomo - Yep, you could use that one if you want, actually.

Answer (score 10):

## SQL Server 2012

You can do it like this,

```
SELECT geography::Point(lat, long, 4326)
```

For more information see my post on Database Administrators, [*"SQL Server Point Constructor or version of ST_Point(x,y)?"*](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/188247/2639)

Comment: If the constructor for `Point` takes x, y arguments, then you will want to switch your ordering as such: `geography::Point(long, lat, 4326)`. Longitude is `x` and Latitude is `y`.

Answer (score 1):

If rounding of the original Long/Lat values occur when using the `CONVERT(VARCHAR,` statement.

Try using:

```
GeoData = geometry:: STGeomFromText('POINT(' + CAST(CAST(X AS decimal(13, 2)) AS varchar) + ' '  + CAST(CAST(Y AS decimal(13, 2)) AS varchar) + ')', 4326)
```

Comment: I have apprehension in using this method, as it involves losing location precision.