# Obtaining Centroid from Polygon in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: qgis, sql-server, centroids

I have several spatial layers created in QGIS that are held as spatial data in SQL Server 2008 R2. What I want to do is to find the centroid (OS Easting and Northing) of the polygon from the geometry. But I want to do this in a view that I have of the data. Each table I want to do this on, has a Geometry field. I've looked at examples of using ST.Centroid, but none of them seem to use a geometry field from a table.

Help on this will be invaluable.

Comment: Is your data in Geometry or Geography types? http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/21108/create-a-geography-geometry-column-from-x-and-y-fields-sql-server-2008

Answer (score 3):

In SQL Server 2008 R2, you should be able to use spatial function: [STCentroid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933847(v=sql.105).aspx)

If you have a geometry column (i.e. called geom) stored in the myTable, you can do the following:

```
select geom.STCentroid() from myTable
```

To create a view:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.View1
  AS
    SELECT     geom, geom.STCentroid() AS CentroidPoint, geom.STCentroid().STAsText() AS Centroid
    FROM       dbo.myTable
GO
```