# Mapping Longitude and Latitude to US state

Tags: latitude-longitude, united-states, point-in-polygon

Is there any database (Gov data or private) or web service that map Longitude and Latitude to US state?

I have the specific Longitude and Latitude of a location and would want to identify the state that this location is in. Then repeat this for thousands and millions of records.

Comment: What software are you using?

Comment: If you have access to a GIS a spatial join to the US Census states layer would work. The layer is publicly available on the census website.

Comment: If you want to use a public webservice http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim#Reverse_Geocoding

Answer (score 2):

Download the [state boundary shapefiles from US Census bureau](https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/tiger-cart-boundary.html).

Load the polygon shapefiles into SQL using [Shape2SQL](http://www.sharpgis.net/page/Shape2SQL).

If you don't already have a geography column on your points table, [add it](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/21138/59).

Do a spatial join using code similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7672934/125400).